# How to use internal variable in tmux send-keys command?

Tags: resize, centos7, tmux, stty

Is there any way can let me do things like `bind-key b send-keys "stty cols #{pane_width} rows #{pane_height}"`

0. I use TMUX.
1. I often need to use ssh to login to CentOS servers which has no `resize` command.
2. I cannot install command in those servers.
3. The server's stty cannot auto resize when I resize the pane of tmux or the window of terminal.

---

I am now using a complicated way to accomplish this.

I write a `display` commend in my `.tmux.conf`, `bind-key b display -p "stty cols #{pane_width} rows #{pane_height}"`.

Then I can copy the `display-message` and paste it to the command line of ssh-server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the variables interpolated using `run-shell`, eg:

```
bind-key b run-shell 'tmux send-keys "stty cols #{pane_width} rows #{pane_height}" Enter'
```